# AngularJS equivalent for event.pageX of jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In jQuery hover [event](http://api.jquery.com/event.pagex/) has `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` properties. Is there any equivalent property for `ng-mouseover` in AngularJs?

I tried using `$event.offsetX` and `$event.x` but they not seem to give same values, also `$event.pageX` always returns undefined.

So what is the equivalent property for `event.pageX` in AngularJs?

Answer (score 1):

The ng-mouseover event does contain pageX and pageY, the event is wrapped around jquery-lite. Angular's version of jQuery.

```
  $scope.mouseOver = function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }


    <a ng-href="#" ng-mouseover="mouseOver($event)">
```

When you pass $event in it, you pass the jQuery event. A simple console.log of the properties gave me the following:

```
pageX: 97
pageY: 85
```

Put together an example here:
https://jsbin.com/nedovoqile/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I am doing same thing. ng-mouseenter=tooltipenter($event) and in javascript alert($event.pageX) displays "undefined" . Is there any initial settings or anything to do ?

Comment: I am using internet explorer 8. But if i use jquery hover for same element then it returns event.pageX properly. But if i use angularjs ng-mouseenter with event then pageX is shown as undefined

Comment: angular doesnt have good support for IE8 don't you have a modern browser tot test in?

Comment: I have latest browsers. But the application should work on all browsers. IE 8 and above